# i want to show inner field of l20n object

Tags: l20n

I have implemented l20n localization.
l20n file:

```
<form {
    title: "Some text"
}>
```

in html i want to get SOme Text using

```
<p data-l10n-id="form.title"></p>
```

But i've got just form.title instead real value. also I am getting right strings instead one level vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of l20n is that you can't do it that way. You have to define an entity for your `p`. If you want to reuse another entity to avoid duplication*, you can do it that way:

```
<title "some text>
<form title:"{{title}}">
<p "{{title}}">
```

And your html like this:

```
<form data-l10n-id='form'>
  <p data-l10n-id='p'></p>
</form>
```

Duplication is actually okay in localization context, as explained in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18184217/29568).

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Just looking for dividing to blocks